# Can std::cout set badbit or failbit with the operator <<? If so, when?

Tags: c++, c++11

Can `std::cout` set the `badbit` or `failbit` with the operator `<<`.  If so, when does this occur?

Comment: Sure. `std::cout << [](std::ostream &os) -> std::ostream & { os.setstate(std::ios::failbit); return os; };` Somehow I doubt that this is what you are asking.

Comment: Fair enough, but, yes, I'm curious about when this can happen without setting the `badbit` or `failbit` directly.  Well, mostly directly.

Comment: `std::cout << static_cast<std::streambuf *>(nullptr);`

Comment: Disk space exhausted or other I/O error. As for failbit, it is only set by formatting operations when they fail. This may happen in any old user-defined `operator<<` (e.g on an attempt to print a value that is not a legal value of its type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::cout` maps to lower-level OS facilities, and anything that could make the OS fail its write will show up as `failbit` or `badbit`.  For example, on Linux, you can cause this to happen by closing stdout:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  close(1);
  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
  return cout.fail(); // returns 1
}
```

(And, because file descriptors are inherited, your calling process may have closed stdout for you.)

Comment: I tried to use `close(1);` to test if it happens on Debian. Close isn't a recognised word. :/ How do I test this?

Comment: @Andy356 - `#include <unistd.h>`? See [the close manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close).

Answer (score 4):

> Can `std::cout` set the `badbit` or `failbit` with the operator `<<`.  If so, when does this occur?

Well in general (not specifically `std::cout` only), these are the reasons output operations may have failed ([as from the cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate)):

> The badbit is set by the following standard library functions:
>
> - `basic_ostream::put` if it fails to insert a character into the output
>     stream, for any reason.
> - `basic_ostream::write` if it fails to insert a
>     character into the output stream, for any reason.
> - Formatted output
>     functions `operator<<`, `std::put_money`, and `std::put_time`, if they
>     encounter the end of the output stream before completing output.
>
> .....
>
> The failbit is set by the following standard library functions:
>
> - `basic_ostream::tellp` on failure
> - The constructors of
>     `std::basic_fstream`, `std::basic_ifstream`, and `std::basic_ofstream` that
>     takes a filename argument, if the file cannot be opened.
> - `basic_fstream::open` , `basic_ifstream::open` , and `basic_ofstream::open`
>     if the file cannot be opened.
> - `basic_fstream::close`,
>     `basic_ifstream::close`, and `basic_ofstream::close` if the file cannot
>     be closed.